# ¿Como hacer que R solo me cuente una vez, un nombre que se repite varias veces?

Tags: base-de-datos, r, archivo, cluster

tengo una base de datos en la que, por ejemplo, el nombre grand thief auto se repite varias veces, y al hacer una tabla con los 10 mejores juegos, al contar que el gta salio en varias consolas pues me lo cuenta varias veces y solo quiero que me lo cuente una, ya que al hacer la grafica pues del top 10 que quiero mostrar solo cuenta como si fuese top 5 ya que el nombre gta esta repetido.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Es importante que añadas lo que hayas intentado hacer hasta ahora y un ejemplo de los datos como texto

Comment: Por cierto, una forma podría ser `length(unique(df$columna))`

Answer (score 0):

Para resolverlo, puedes utilizar en la consulta la cláusula DISTINCT para asegurarte de que cada juego se cuente solo una vez. Aquí tienes un ejemplo:

```
SELECT DISTINCT nombre_juego, plataforma, puntuacion
FROM tabla_juegos
ORDER BY puntuacion DESC
LIMIT 10;
```